# Windows 10 login screen is shifted partly off the monitor after a non-admin user logs out

Tags: windows-10, display, user-accounts, logout

I just set up a Windows 10 computer for my parents.  I made an administrator account for me, and non-admin accounts for my mom and dad.

I have noticed a problem with the login screen in the following situations:

- When my mom or dad uses the computer and then logs out, the subsequent login screen will be shifted partly off the monitor.
- When my mom or dad uses the computer and then shuts down, the next bootup results in the login screen being shifted partly off the monitor.
- When any user, including me, tries to switch users while logged in, the login screen will be shifted partly off the monitor.

[image]

When the problem happens, logging in may or may not fix the problem - the user's desktop could still be shifted partly off the monitor.  One sure way to clear up the problem (until it happens again) is to restart Windows.

This problem doesn't happen for me at all when I log out.